# formula to change the value in a cell when a linked cell's value changes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As a beginner, I am looking for info for a formula.  I have researched but am not finding help.

On an excel monthly sheet, I have a column of cells with date formatting related to contact member follow-up.  When I change the date in a cell (most recent contact for that person) I would like to show how many times I have changed the date that month.
Ex. Column B shows the last date the person was contacted
Column J shows how many times the person was contacted this month.

Any advice is appreciated, but please remember I am a beginner. - Thank you!

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4747-excel-count-changes-to-a-cell.html    This link demonstrates a VBA option for counting the number of changes that occur in a given cell.

Comment: Thank you for a rapid response! I am already using it!

Answer (score 0):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rINT As Range, r As Range, B As Range
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    Set rINT = Intersect(B, Target)
    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rINT
            rw = r.Row
            With Cells(rw, "J")
                If .Value = "" Or .Value = 0 Then
                    .Value = 1
                Else
                    .Value = .Value + 1
                End If
            End With
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It will place a count in column **J** each time a cell in column **B** is updated in that row.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**